# Twitter share button not using custom url or text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I have a link like so

```
= link_to "https://twitter.com/share", class: "twitter-share-button", data: { url: "https://google.com", text: hack.body, via: "GhettoLifeHack_", hashtags: "ghettolifehack" } do
  = image_tag "Tweet", alt: "Social Twitter tweet button"
```

and no matter how much I change the data-url value, the pre-tweet confirmation page always prepopulates the tweet form field with the url of the referring page, not the one I specified. It also ignores my custom data-text as well.

Why is this happening?

I also have this minified script

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

that I got from here https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#tweet
Removing that script doesn't seem to change anything.

---

edit: upon trying using `:'data-url'` attributes directly, the output html is the same.

I am testing hardcoded strings and dynamically generated urls at the same time. The first is the dynamic one.

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-via="GhettoLifeHack_" data-url="http://localhost:3000/hacks/1" data-text="asdf comment body" data-hashtags="ghettolifehack">

    <img src="/images/Tweet" alt="Tweet" title=""></img>

</a>
```

The second is the hard coded strings

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share" data-via="GhettoLifeHack_" data-url="httpL//google.com" data-text="custom text" data-hashtags="ghettolifehack">

    <img src="/images/Tweet" alt="Tweet" title=""></img>

</a>
```

I've tested on development and in production. Both have the same behavior of pre-populating the tweet form with the referring url, rather than the specified url and text.

This works in Chrome for me but not in Firefox 32

Comment: Does it work if you directly give the custom attribute, such as
= link_to "https://twitter.com/share", class: "twitter-share-button", :'data-url' => 'url', :'data-text' => hack.body

Comment: modifying the data-url and data-text attributes don't become placeholders or pre-filled form text in the pre-tweet page, as mentioned. Are you talking about using direct string hashes instead of hash-within-hash notation? I already see those attributes correctly displayed when I use the browser inspector. If changing that equivalent syntax to what you're saying makes it work, then that means the hash-within-hash syntax doesn't work... at which point I'll flip my table because that makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: also, i don't think i should be doing `:'data-url'`. It should be `:data-url` if anything.

Comment: Yes. You do not have to change the attributes. Just see if using direct string hashes works ? This would pinpoint if the problem is with the way we are specifying the attributes or it lies somewhere else. I believe it is because of this only. Also, could you please use the debug console using F12 in the browser and see the exact HTML code being generated?

Comment: I used the single quotes because we have a dash sign.

Comment: @addicted20015 I implemented your suggestion. The results are the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62048/discussion-between-addicted20015-and-gwho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided by you is perfectly fine and should work as expected.

Many site issues can be caused by corrupt cookies or cache. Try to clear both cookies and the cache.  I would suggest you to look into the [following link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/951772) to see why it is not working in firefox

Answer (score 0):

The issue was specific to firefox browser. I'm not sure what addon or setting is causing the conflicts, but it is working perfectly find in chrome, including the popup window.